# display ppt files in UIWebview in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I want to display MSOffice extensions in webview. Is this possible?
I've tried this:

```
NSString *resourceDocPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]];

NSString *filePath = [resourceDocPath
                      stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myPDF.pdf"];
[pdfData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGSize screenSize = rect.size;
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,screenSize.width,screenSize.height)];



// Now create Request for the file that was saved in your documents folder
//UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 250, self.view.frame.size.width, 300)];

NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:fileurl];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];

[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

But I get the message:

> "An error occured while reading the document".

Comment: why u used "myPDF.pdf" i guess you want to display ppt??

Comment: where you have place your ppt file? within project or you will download from server??

Comment: How you get value in "fileurl"?

Answer (score 0):

Try below if your `ppt` file is drag dropped in your project

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
    [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
    pathForResource:@"FileName" ofType:@"ppt"]isDirectory:NO]]];
```

If you are getting your file from server in form of `NSData` then use below

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[@"yourURL" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSData* responseData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: url];

[webView loadData:responseData MIMEType:@"application/ppt"
 textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
```

Comment: what should i use in the place of responseData...@ajay_nasa...still am getting same error an erorr occured while reading the document

Comment: [webView loadData:filename MIMEType:@"application/ppt" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fileurl]];
        [self.view addSubview:webView];

Comment: where you have placed your ppt file?

Comment: getting file name from url and when i click on that file name ,want to display that  ppt file....

Comment: please check my updated answer and let me know it works for you or not?

Comment: Thq mr.ajay_nasa.. ) but i am getting white screen...couldn't get any data

Comment: NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[fileurl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        NSData* responseData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        
        CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        CGSize screenSize = rect.size;
        webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,screenSize.width,screenSize.height)];
        
        [webView loadData:responseData MIMEType:@"application/ppt"
         textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fileurl]];
        [self.view addSubview:webView];